# how Make Cookie-Free Domain with wordpress

Tags: wordpress, cookies, dns

I created a website (filhadath.com) and I want to create a cookie-free domain. I made a subdomain, then set that in wp-config :

```
define("WP_CONTENT_URL", "http://static.filhadath.com");
define("COOKIE_DOMAIN", "filhadath.com");
```

I use a CDN so I added static to Cloudflare. Unfortunately, CSS and javascript isn't loaded by the website when the new wp-content.php is in place.

Comment: Did you find a solution? i'm interested !:)